# How is a one-hot code called, if zero is acepted, too?

Tags: encoding

All know the one-hot code (aka. 1-out-of-N code).

This strict code has exact one *One* in each binary word. But what if I allow also zero *Ones*?

A 4-bit onehot example:

```
0 -> 0001
1 -> 0010
2 -> 0100
3 -> 1000
```

**Is there a name for the following code?**

```
0 -> 0000
1 -> 0001
2 -> 0010
3 -> 0100
4 -> 1000
```

*(I hope it's on-topic at EE.SE)*

Comment: What does zero ones look like? 0000?

Comment: Yes that's the code word

Comment: "One hot encoding with the LSB removed?"

Comment: "One hot with a state that's not"?

Comment: It's certainly not called one-hot anymore. It's simply an encoding in which not all possibilities are covered/used/allowed. Doubt it has a name.

Comment: Munged mess? Jury-rigged engineering? Custom cipher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found `zero_onehot` in the [Open Verification Language (OVL)](http://www.accellera.org/downloads/standards/ovl).

Answer (score 1):

This code is often used in FPGAs to encode state machines. Typically one bit will be used to encode each state.

It's not very efficient in the encoding, but then one-bit registers are a cheap resource.

It **is** very efficient when decoding what to do, as if you can guarrantee that only one bit it hot, very little gating is needed.

It is extremely efficient is debugging, one state <-> one bit really helps the human mind figure out what's going on.

In those circumstances, the '0000' encoding appears naturally for the 'power on' or 'idle' condition. I've not seen anybody feel the need to describe it as anything other than a 'one hot', as it's kid of obvious what's going on.n

If you really must, then you will want something that is as snappy as 'one hot', like perhaps 'one hot or not', 'none or one hot', 'one or none hot', but 'one hot with zeros' is pretty clear.

Comment: I know for what one-codes are used, the question was for the name of a code that violates the 1-out-of-N rule. Yes I could give it a new name like `BlubCode`, but reinventing the wheels is no good design strategy....

Comment: Once you know what it's used for, you might question whether the '0000' state violates anything, and so whether other people feel the need to use anything other than the 'one hot' description. Have a look at [forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_Forms). What did you think of my several suggestions?